# Active Directory memberOf LDAP syntax

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sun, identity-management

I want to add a user (from Sun IDM to Active Directory) to more than one group.
The command memberOf: `CN=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=AAA,DC=AAA` is for only one and I want to add a second one immediatly after the first; e.g.:
`memberOf: CN=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=AAA,DC=AAA` **and** `CN=BBB,OU=BBB,DC=BBB,DC=BBB`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you're doing the adding, there are a couple of ways of doing this. `MemberOf` is a multi-valued attribute. If you're using an LDIF file, or direct LDAP syntax, you just add multiple `MemberOf` statements:

```
Department: Human Resources
MemberOf: CN=AAA,OU=BBB,DC=CCC,DC=DDD
MemberOf: CN=AAB,OU=BBB,DC=CCC,DC=DDD
MemberOf: CN=ABC,OU=CDE,DC=CCC,DC,DDD
Full Name: Milton Ives
```

Comment: I'm using Sun IDM and I don't have the possibility to add new line like in your example. I can write only one string. There are something special chars to give to him the CR, like \n or <br>?

Comment: I've never used the Sun IDM so can't help you there.

Comment: Solved. Sun IDM think about attributes as lists, so I had to give him the attribute as list and merge the attributes in it.