# ldap query active directory: all users with their assigned groups or groups with their members

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ldap, query

I'm trying to make a ldap query which I can run in active directory tool, so I can have an overview of all users with their groups.

What do I need to add to this script to see the groups of these users ?

&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user) 
(givenName=*)(sn=*))

Thanks,

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/275259/active-directory-memberof-ldap-syntax/275262#275262

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory

Answer (score 3):

This is not a script, this is a LDAP filter which means :

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=*)(sn=*))`

Retrieve the entries which are of the type `person` AND `user` AND
which possess these attributes populated : `givenName` AND `sn`

If you want to retrieve the groups which these users are member of, configure on the tool that you want to also retrieve the attribute `memberOf` from the users entries filtered.

As stated in the Subject of the question, if you want to know the members of the group `MyGroupName`, retrieve the `member` attribute of this group filtered by a LDAP filter, for example, such as :

`(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=MyGroupName))`

Comment: How do I combine the two requirements than ? :s

Comment: What do you mean by combine? You retrieve either the groups with their members OR the users with their groups.